# Please break down this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Republicans, meanwhile, have been growing increasingly restless, with the House Oversight Committee probing Trump's security protocols for discussing classified information at his weekend retreat in Mar-a-Lago, and Senate majority leader Mitch McConnell suggesting that the Senate investigation of Russian interference in the election would expand.

I'm not sure what this means. However, I tried to construct a section of the sentence I especially have difficulty understanding it. This is my interpretation.

The original phrase: the House Oversight Committee probing Trump's security protocols for discussing classified information

My attempt to paraphrase: the House Oversight Committee investigating Trump's security system to discuss secret information

Source: TIME February 27/ March 6, 2017: White House Chaos Theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help

> Republicans, meanwhile, have been growing increasingly restless
>   *Republicans have become restless*
>
> with the House Oversight Committee probing Trump's security protocols
>   *while/because the House Oversight Committee is looking into Trump's steps to make sure things were secure*
>
> for discussing classified information at his weekend retreat in Mar-a-Lago
>   *when discussing classified information at his weekend retreat in Mar-a-Lago (a nonsecure location)*
>
> and Senate majority leader Mitch McConnell suggesting that the Senate investigation of Russian interference in the election would expand
>   *Senate majority leader Mitch McConnell suggests the Senate investigation of Russian interference should be bigger.*

The phrase

> security protocol

are the steps to take to make sure *something* is secure and remains private.
A *protocol* can mean the step-by-step instructions.

Comment: So in other words, the House Oversight Committee is looking into a way to make sure things are secure because they are in his retreat which isn't private enough?

Comment: Almost, they are looking into whether Trump **already had** a way to make sure things were secure. The Committee is investigating whether the protocols already existed, they may or may not make recommendations.

Comment: "probing" = "looking into" it does not mean "recommending"

Comment: "for", in this case, means "when"?

Comment: "**for** discussing classified information" = "**whenever** discussing classified information"